# How to develop Automatically Generated News

Tags: mysql, sql, database, web, computer-science

Before start this project,
I don't know what I need to do first.
First given input data stream of real world events, then this output articles or at least headlines that look like they were written by a human. This kind of thing was done by the Washington Post to generate tweets about Olympic events: http://www.recode.net/2016/8/5/12383340/washington-post-olympics-software

Answer (score 1):

You're asking a very vague question.  There are a lot of problems to solve in order to write something like the Washington Post did for the olympics tweets.

This site is more aimed at resolving specific technical / implementation questions than "I don't even know how to begin" type questions.